# File Copy Python

Tags: python

I wrote a small Python Script to copy data from USB Stick to my Desktop but it isn´t working...

```
while True:

    while True:

        if os.path.ismount("/media/usb0"):

            print ("USB erkannt")

            for filenames in glob("/media/usb0/DCIM/*.jpg"):

                shutil.copy2("/media/usb0/DCIM"+filenames, "/home/pi/Desktop/lh/"+filenames)

            break

        sleep(1)

    sleep(1)
```

And here is the repeat:

```
USB erkannt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/usbTest.py", line 12, in <module>
    shutil.copy2("/media/usb0/DCIM"+filenames, "/home/pi/Desktop/lh/"+filenames)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 244, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 107, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/usb0/DCIM/media/usb0/DCIM/20170318_120140.jpg'
```

On the Stick the structure is like /DMCI/examples.jpg

And 20170318_120140.jpg' exists

Comment: Why do you have 2 while loops when only 1 would do? Also, this will endlessly copy the files (overwrite?).

Comment: The `filename` variable contains the full path for the file. You don't have to append it with `/media/usb0/DCIM` in `copy2()` function

Comment: To run the script endless

Comment: you got this duplicated: */media/usb0/DCIM/media/usb0/DCIM/* edit:  @kuro beat  me to it

Comment: @FelixStepponat If you get rid of the `break`, you can get rid of the external while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are already iterating over every file in

```
for filename in glob("/media/usb0/DCIM/*.jpg"):
```

Now, when you try to access `"/media/usb0/DCIM"+filename` it will contain the first part twice, as you can see in your error:`'/media/usb0/DCIM/media/usb0/DCIM/20170318_120140.jpg'`

Try just using

```
for filename in glob("/media/usb0/DCIM/*.jpg"):
    shutil.copy2(filename, "/home/pi/Desktop/lh/"+filename)
```

I'll also guess that you maybe want `"/home/pi/Desktop/lh/" + os.path.basename(filename)` So you only have the old filename as new filename and not the whole path as new filename.